# Remove from Firebase Database - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

This is how my Firebase database looks like: [FireBase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko3Ly.png)

This data comes from the following code:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Fetching your location")

    dismissUIElements(value: false)

    let location = locations[locations.count - 1]

    if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        let userLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        let userLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude


        saveCurrentLocation(long: userLongitude, lat: userLatitude)

    }
}

func saveCurrentLocation(long: Double, lat: Double){

    let geofireRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Locations")
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)

    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    geoFire.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long), forKey: userID!) { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("An error occured: \(String(describing: error))")

            self.dismissUIElements(value: true)

        } else {
            print("Saved location successfully!")

            self.dismissUIElements(value: true)

            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

In another View Controller, I want to remove only the location of the user, not the complete child named "Locations". The code,

```
func deleteUserLocation(){

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Locations").child(userID!).removeValue()

}
```

This deletes the whole 'folder' named "Locations" instead of the particular child.

How may I delete only the child which is named after the user's uid?

Comment: Are there multiple childs under Locations or just the one?

Comment: There would be multiple when multiple user log in.

Comment: Why is this a problem for you? (Locations being deleted when it doesn't have any children) It will just be created again when you store a new value in it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine but in Firebase you can't have empty containers (Dictionaries or Arrays).

So if you only have 1 element and remove it the parent element gets removed too, but will be created next time you add another child.

Comment: Ok thanks. So a work around this problem could be keeping one account logged in at all time?

Comment: Ok thanks. So a work around this problem could be keeping one account logged in at all time?

Comment: You should consider the possibility of "Locations" being optional. Will exists whenever it has children.